# dom to image library generate low quality image

Tags: javascript

I used dom-to-image to download div content as image but it gives me a low quality image which is not clear
my code :

```
<script> 
    var node = document.getElementById('my-certificate');
    var btn = document.getElementById('download-btn');

    var options = {
        quality: 0.99 
    };
    
    btn.onclick = function() {
      domtoimage.toBlob(node, options)
        .then(function(blob) {
          window.saveAs(blob, 'my-certification.png');
        });
    
    }
</script>
```

any idea in how to generate better quality ?

Comment: As far as I understand from to the documentation (https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image), the `quality` option is relevant only for JPEG images (`toJpeg()` function); have you tried generating a .jpg instead of a .png file? Does the image quality stay the same?

Comment: i have no experience in javascript so i can't know how to generate jpeg instead of png

Comment: all you have to do  is reading the documentation at the link I inserted in the previous comment; you will find an example there. In general, whenever you use a third-party library, you should read the documentation... especially if you have not enough coding experience to understand what it does just by looking at the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js" integrity="sha256-c9vxcXyAG4paArQG3xk6DjyW/9aHxai2ef9RpMWO44A=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

The following code helps to convert DOM to a PNG image and then convert it to a PDF and download it.

```
var scale = 2;
var domNode = document.getElementById("content2");
var fileName = 'Test File';

domtoimage.toPng(domNode, {
    width: domNode.clientWidth * scale,
    height: domNode.clientHeight * scale,
    style: {
      transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
      transformOrigin: "top left"
    }
  })
  .then(function (imgData) {
    var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", [
      $("#content2").width(),
      $("#content2").height()
    ]);
    pdf.addImage(
      imgData,"PNG",0,0,
      $("#content2").width(),
      $("#content2").height()
    );
    pdf.save(fileName);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use width and height in the options to scale up the node before the image will be renderd. (If you do not, the quality is like a screen-shoot)

```
 var options = {
    quality: 0.99,
    width: 2000,
    height: 2000,
};
```

Comment: this code gives me a white image with dimensions of 2000 X 2000 and my image put in the left top corner of the white image

Comment: <script> 
  var node = document.getElementById('my-certificate');
  var btn = document.getElementById('download-btn');

  var options = {
   quality: 0.99,
   width: 4000,
   height: 4000,
  };
  
  btn.onclick = function() {
    domtoimage.toJpeg(node, options)
   .then(function(img) {
     window.saveAs(img, 'my-certification.jpeg');
   });
  
  }
 </script>

Comment: show me your htm-code of  'my-certificate' you have to chnage it to a bigger size before you get the image

Comment: may be the size is too big

Comment: my html div i made it width 100% and responsive of any screen size

Comment: make it bigger than the screensize, maybe 2000px

Comment: <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
    <div id="my-certificate" class="certificate" >

      <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/bg.jpg');?>" style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 50vw;"/>
      <div class="sname"><?php echo $name;?></div>
      <div class="grade"><?php echo $natega->grade;?></div>
      <div class="percen"><?php echo $percentage;?> %</div>

    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: for testing set the width to 2000px and height to 2000px

Comment: i made it with bootstrap 4

Comment: did you chane the size for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var scale = 2;
domtoimage.toBlob(domNode, {
 width: domNode.clientWidth * scale,
 height: domNode.clientHeight * scale,
 style: {
  transform: 'scale('+scale+')',
  transformOrigin: 'top left'
})
```

This worked for me.